# D3.Drag.Behaviour not working as it should

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using D3 Drag to drag some circles around the canvas. I then have them with fixed positions. However, I wish to position them from a distance from another svg element that I have created:

```
 node.attr("transform", function(d,i) { return "translate ("+ arc[i].centroid() +")" +"translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")"; })
```

When dragged the circles do not drag until multiple clicks of the mouse & is usually far from the actual mouse hand.

I know I can get rid of the centroid, but would like to know a work around this problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zc4z9/10/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jump you are getting on the first drag attempt results from the fact that the translate on line 57 doesn't match the one further down. To avoid the jump, make lines 57 and 76 match. Change 57 to:

```
d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate ("+ arc[i].centroid() +")" +"translate("+d.x+","+d.y+")");
```

To get this to work, I had to pass d and i as parameters in line 52:

```
.on("drag", function(d, i) {
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zc4z9/11/